# How to estimate my contract code size? it is too big to deploy now

Tags: gas, truffle-deployment

I think my contract is too big to deploy, because I got
`Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually. Error: oversized data` when I am trying to deploy on ropsten network. (but it works fine on testrpc, because I set a very large number of gas limit)

So I want to estimate my code size to be deployed in truffle test. I know how to estimate gas to run a function in contract using `estimateGas()`, but I don't know how to estimate gas(or code size?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How to estimate gas for deploying a smart contract

I'm using the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), Appendix G, page 25 as reference.

The cost of gas to deploy your contract can be calculated like this:

- 21000 because all transactions pay this (Gtransaction)
- 32000 because is a contract creation (Gcreate)

Your transaction will have input data, which will cost you in gas:

- 4 for each byte with value zero in your input data (Gtxdatazero)
- 68 for each non zero byte in your input data (Gtxdatanonzero)

Initialising variables and running the constructor, costs you:

- 20000 for each SSTORE when the storage value is set to non-zero (Gsset)
- 5000 for each SSTORE when the storage value is set to zero (Gsreset)
- additional gas for each OPCODE your constructor is executing (see reference)

Finally, you have to pay to store your code, and that will cost you:

- 200 for each byte of code you store on the state.

When you compile your code, you get your bytecode, and that's where you can find all the OPCODES your smart contract executes.

You will also get your running (or deployed) bytecode, which is the code that will be stored on the state. It's equal to the bytecode minus the initialisation and constructor code (that are not stored in the state).

## How to know the code size using a truffle javascript test file

You can use the following code in a js file inside the test folder:

```
var YourContract = artifacts.require("YourContract");

contract('YourContract', function(accounts) {
  it("get the size of the contract", function() {
    return YourContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      var bytecode = instance.constructor._json.bytecode;
      var deployed = instance.constructor._json.deployedBytecode;
      var sizeOfB  = bytecode.length / 2;
      var sizeOfD  = deployed.length / 2;
      console.log("size of bytecode in bytes = ", sizeOfB);
      console.log("size of deployed in bytes = ", sizeOfD);
      console.log("initialisation and constructor code in bytes = ", sizeOfB - sizeOfD);
    });  
  });
});
```

Afterwards, run `truffle test`.

Comment: Thank you for good answer. But I asked about contract code size not the gas amount to run my contract. But it is very informative. From https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md, the contract size is limited within 24k bytes. But I don't know how to check my contract size using truffle test script (or it is not possible by truffle? I have to parse build file to check the byte size after compile?

Comment: When you compile your contract with truffle, you get a json file (where you can find the abi), normally in the build folder. There, you can measure the bytecode, and you will get the size of your code. Remember, in bytecode, each byte is represented by 2 letters.

Comment: can it be done in my test javascript code?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it works for you?

Comment: It works fine! So the sum of sideofB and sizeofD should be less than 24k?

Comment: From https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md we can read "The solution is to put a hard cap on the size of an object that can be **saved to the blockchain**". Only deployed bytecode is saved to the blockchain, so its only sizeOfD that needs to be smaller than 24k.

Comment: Thanks! How to know the contract code size from REMIX IDE ?